# Use navigationOptions in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using navigatioinOptions in component.

The problem is the space is always leaving while I use navigationOptions.

Here's my code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  headerLeft: ...
  }
}
```

I have attached image file.

Please help me.
Thanks for your time.
[image]

Comment: Add a `headerRight` but keep it empty: `return <Text></Text>` for example

Comment: It's not working on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your screenshot represents `headerLeft` alone, therefore a layout not conforming to the typical headerLeft|title|headerRight arrangement, I'd suggest that you move all those elements into `header` alone. That way you'll have the whole space for everything that you need there, i.e.:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    header: (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          paddingTop: 21,
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
          <Text>This is 100% wide</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    ),
  };
};
```

which looks like:

[image: Rendered header]

Note that while using the header this way you will need to take care of all platform specific styles yourself. You may find [Header.js' source code](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Header/Header.js) helpful for that.